# "End of Statement Expected" VB.NET Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, syntax-error

I keep getting this error: "End of Statement Expected".

Here is where the error is in my code:

**The parts with * * around it are what is showing up as an error.**

```
Declare Function capGetDriverDescriptionA Lib"avicap32.dll" _
(ByVal wDriverIndex As Short, _
ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal *cbName* *AsInteger*, _
ByVal lpszVer As String, _
ByVal cbVer As Integer) *AsBoolean*

'--The capCreateCaptureWindow function creates a capture window--
Declare Function capCreateCaptureWindowA Lib "avicap32.dll" _
(ByVal lpszWindowName As String, ByVal dwStyle As Integer, _
ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal nWidth As Integer, _
ByVal nHeight As Short, ByVal hWnd As Integer, _
ByVal nID As Integer) As Integer

'--This function sends the specified message to a window or windows--
Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal Msg As Integer, _
ByVal wParam As Integer, _
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)> ByVal lParam As Object) As Integer

'--Sets the position of the window relative to the screen buffer--
Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib"user32"Alias"SetWindowPos" _
(ByVal hwnd As Integer, _
ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, _
ByVal y *AsInteger*, _
ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, _
ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer

'--This function destroys the specified window--
Declare Function DestroyWindow Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hndw As Integer) As Boolean

'---used to identify the video source---
Dim CamSource As Integer

'---used as a window handle---
Dim hWnd As Integer
```

Does anyone know how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Please post a **minimal** (and, if relevant, *complete*) example next time. Most of your code isn’t relevant to the problem at all.

Comment: Never mind. I figured out that there was no space between "As" and "Integer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve written `AsInteger` and `AsBoolean` instead of `As Integer` and `As Boolean`.